# Simple way to communicate between C# app and Python app

Tags: c#, python, mono, zeromq

I've got a C# app running under Windows and Linux. I would like to implement a way to communicate with it through a Python script.

I've already tried using ZeroMQ library, and it was working right when the C# app was running on Windows - I could send/receive messages on both ends. But I failed miserably when I tried to use on Linux/Mono - the app crashed, kernel32 exception. I tried recompiling the libzmq.dll, using the tutorials, but I can't get it right.

Is there any other way to do this, or should I stick with ZeroMQ and try to get it running on Linux/Mono?

Comment: The TCP socket solution is clearly _a_ solution, if thats not suitable can you provide some notes on the 'type' of communication (ie 1 way, 2 way, simple text messages / some sort of object access?) and what the C# app is (ie a service /  its an desktop app and you want to allow python scripting / ???)

Comment: Either that or you expose an api over http from the c# application.  You basically create an instance of WebServer and handle GET or POST request. It all depends on what your communication requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use NetMQ, C# port of ZeroMQ that runs on Windows and Mono without 32/64bit issue.

https://github.com/zeromq/netmq
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetMQ/

Comment: Perfect solution to my problem. The communication works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open up a TCP or UDP socket and communicate through that.